# RedisCluster MGET with pipeline

Tags: python, redis, pipeline, redis-cluster

I am trying to perform an MGET operation on my Redis with the pipeline to increase performance.
I have tried doing MGET in one go as well as as a batch flow

```
from rediscluster import RedisCluster
ru = RedisCluster(startup_nodes=[{"host": "somecache.aws.com", "port": "7845"}], 
        decode_responses=True, 
        skip_full_coverage_check=True)
    
pipe = ru.pipeline()        
# pipe.mget(keys)
    
for i in range(0, len(keys), batch_size):
    temp_list = keys[i:i + batch_size]
    pipe.mget(temp_list)

resp = pipe.execute()
```

So far I am getting the error

```
raise RedisClusterException("ERROR: Calling pipelined function {0} is blocked 
when running redis in cluster mode...".format(func.__name__))
rediscluster.exceptions.RedisClusterException: ERROR: 
Calling pipelined function mget is blocked when running redis in cluster mode...
```

What I want to know is that

1. Does RedisCluster pipelined MGET?
2. If not then is there any other lib that I can use to archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out we can not use MGET with the pipeline, below is m final solution

```
from rediscluster import RedisCluster
    
def redis_multi_get(rc: RedisCluster, keys: list):
    pipe = rc.pipeline()
    [pipe.get(k) for k in keys]
    return pipe.execute()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rc = RedisCluster(startup_nodes=[{"host": host, "port": port}], decode_responses=True, skip_full_coverage_check=True)
    keys = rc.keys(PREFIX + '*')
    cache_hit = redis_multi_get(rc, keys)
```